# Babel/Webpack configuration for ES6 with BrowserSync (React-hot-loader)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, browser-sync, react-hot-loader

I've looked at the setup @gaearon provides through the React Hot Loader recipe (https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) and as this seems to be exactly what I'm after to learn ES6 and React I thought I'd use it as a starting point.

Cloning the repo got me up and runnning and everything was great. Then I noticed two issues:

1. It uses `v13` of React and I want to use the new approach of writing components (and using `react-dom`)
2. I also want to use ES6's approach for imports (e.g. `import { Foo } from Bar;`)

So I figure, simple, I'll just update the dependancies to suite my needs. Here is an extract from my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ."
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14.8",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
  "browser-sync": "^2.11.2",
  "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
  "webpack": "^1.12.14",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
}
```

This lead me to make some minor adjustments to the way Webpack is handling the bundling. Here is my current `webpack.config.js` file:

```
// For instructions about this file refer to
// webpack and webpack-hot-middleware documentation
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'js'),

  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './main'
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'js'),
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then I make a quick adjustment to get the React components inline with the new approach for `react-dom`... here is the `main.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

And the basic 'hello world' component itself:

```
import React from 'react';

const name = 'world';
const HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h2 className="hello-world">
              <span className="hello-world__i">Hello, {name}</span>
            </h2>
        )
    }
});

export default HelloWorld;
```

Now on running `npm start` I naively hoped this would just all work and I'd go skipping through the streets with a grin on my face... alas not. **The console returns an error for which I cannot distinguish the cause:**

```
ERROR in ./app/js/main.js                             
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\app\js\main.js: Unknown
 option: C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\react\react.js.Children. Check out http://babe
ljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more info              
    at Logger.error (C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file
\logger.js:39:11)                                     
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\trans
formation\file\options\option-manager.js:267:20)      
    at C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\optio
n-manager.js:349:14                                   
    at C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\optio
n-manager.js:369:24                                   
    at Array.map (native)                             
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:364:20)    
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:348:10)      
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:307:14)      
    at OptionManager.init (C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:465:10)              
    at File.initOptions (C:\tutch_build\webpack.react-hot-loader\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:194:75)                                 
 @ multi main
```

What am I doing wrong? I've checked over the creation of the components and that all appears correct... Is it an issue with conflicting dependencies? Or have I simply created messed up the webpack config?

I've throw my whole project onto github to make it easy to replicate the issue, if this helps... it can be found here: https://github.com/sheixt/webpack.react-hot-loader

Comment: Please note that react-hot has been deprecated in favor of react-transform. You can use [babel-preset-react-hmre](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-hmre) instead. Perhaps that will help with your problem.

Comment: use this boilerplate.. it's also by @gaearon and is more updated https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the suggestions.Which is more of a suitable solution the boilerplate or hmre?

Comment: I think the boilerplate is more production ready. react-hot isn't quite deprecated yet while react-transform is still in early development. If you just want to start coding react right away I would use the boilerplate it has all the stuff you wanted in your OP.

Comment: In my project I import react as `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: Yeah the "Either of the technologies it relies upon may change drastically or get deprecated any day. " line from `react-transform-hmr` is worrying to say the least

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
 query: {
          presets: [ 'es2015', 'react','stage-0']
        }
```